# Set a CQ5 component to editable or not editable

Tags: java, aem, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

Is it posible if i want to set a cq5 component editable in page A, but not editable in page B.

For example: at page A, i have C component we allow authors to open dialog and edit the component. But we do not allow authors to open dialog to edit component C on Page B.
I try to research cq:EditConfig [link](http://labs.sixdimensions.com/blog/2014-01-08/the-great-and-powerful-cq-editconfig/), but It's not enough documentation to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set ComponentContext.BYPASS_COMPONENT_HANDLING_ON_INCLUDE_ATTRIBUTE before the include, and remove it after the include.

Set:

```
slingRequest.setAttribute(ComponentContext.BYPASS_COMPONENT_HANDLING_ON_INCLUDE_ATTRIBUTE, true);
```

Remove:

```
slingRequest.removeAttribute(ComponentContext.BYPASS_COMPONENT_HANDLING_ON_INCLUDE_ATTRIBUTE);
```

More details are here: https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/boilerplates.html

You can write a Sling component filter:

And you can check the page and the component, and if you want to disable editing, just set the attribute, do the filter, and unset the attribute...